# Spring @Transactional does not work in JUnit test?

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit4, spring-test, transactional

I am using Spring 3.2, Hibernate and JUnit 4.

My Dao class is as follows:

`@Transactional public class SomeDaoImpl implements SomeDao {`

The update operations on this work if executed directly from web application. However, I am seeing that junit integration tests that exercise the update methods do not actually persist the changes. Is something rolling the transactions back when junit methods are executed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/testing.html#testing-tx), transactions are *not* persisted in test contexts in Spring. As mentioned, although unusual, if you still need to do so you can use [`@TransactionConfiguration`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations) and [`@Rollback`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations) to change the default behavior.

Answer (score 13):

DAOs should not be transactional.  How can a DAO know if it should participate in a larger transaction?

Services ought to own transactions in the typical Spring layered architecture.

It's typical to run your unit tests for databases in such a way that they do roll back.  You don't want your tests to alter the database, unless you've set up a test database that you can drop and recreate at will.

The question ought to be: How do your tests, as written, commit the transaction?  If you never commit, you'll never see the records.

Comment: sorry should have added that i am using hibernate for persistence.

Comment: It wasn't supposed to be a comment on your answer anyway :-). BTW the best practice you mentioned above is well published. I think you got lost in trying to be pedantic and forgot to answer the real question!

Comment: If the best practice is so well published, why are you not following it?  I have no way to conclude what you know based on what you posted.  And I think I did answer the question.  The fact that you didn't commit is pertinent.  Others have suggested the same thing.  How is that not answering the question?

Answer (score 8):

[From the "Testing" section of the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html), you can use the

```
 @Rollback(false)
```

annotation if you don't want SpringJUnit4ClassRunner to roll back your transactions.